# Jquery THIS for mouseover event on dynamically generated div

Tags: jquery, this, mouseover

The following function triggered on mouseover is trying to fetch the html text from a dynamically generated object; it returns undefined (I am trying to get the "test")

```
HTML (generated by php):
<div class="info" onmouseover=hoverdivOpen(event,"popupUserInfoDiv")>test</div>

JS:
function hoverdivOpen(e,divid){
  var v = $(this).text();
  console.log(v);
 // ... rest of code to open the popup div....//
}
```

Is there a way to deal with this issue like `on()` for click events ?

Comment: How are you calling this function? Is it from an `on()` handler?

Comment: it is triggered by mouseover in the html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Async issues are commonly a source of similar-looking problems (you can't access a DOM node before it exists), but it doesn't seem like that's what's going on in this case.

In the context in which you're invoking the mouseover function, `this` refers to the [window](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window) object, not the element that triggered the event.

The element is available on the `event` object (as `event.target`).

You can get its contents using `innerHTML` -- no jQuery required, and you don't need to pass through a class name to use as a selector.

```js
function hoverdivOpen(e){
    console.log(e.target.innerHTML);
}
```

```html
    <div onmouseover=hoverdivOpen(event)>test</div>
```

In the jQuery equivalent -- which allows you to separate your html a bit more from the scripting -- `this` refers to the DOM element instead of the window, so you use that instead of the `event`:

```js
$('#foo').on("mouseover", function() {
  console.log($(this).html()); // jQuery equivalent to this.innerHTML
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="foo">test</div>
```

Comment: that was some great insight. thanks ! I understand that the element that triggered the event is my `div` but could you please precise what is the "window object" ? Im confused because as far as I understand I only have one object `<div>` even more confused why the `on()` method did not work like for click events.

Comment: The window object is the browser window. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window

Comment: I updated the answer with an explanation of the equivalent jquery code.

Comment: Thanks Daniel I understand better the window object but I wanted to let you know that the Jquery answer does not work for some reason; it gives the following error: `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'context.createDocumentFragment')` JS is working fine

Comment: `createDocumentFragment` should only come up if you're referencing, well, document fragments that aren't part of the DOM.  I'm honestly not sure how that's happening for you. I'd start by comparing your code to the snippet above (which does not throw that error) to see what's different.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You can use `.on()` delegated event handling with mouseenter, mouseover and mouseleave  like this `$(document).on("mouseover", "input", function() {});`

```js
$("body").append('<input type="text" value="Hello World">');
$(document).on("mouseover", "input", function() {
    console.log( "Hi!" + $(this).val()); // jQuery 1.4.3+
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Answer for updated question**
You are confusing `jQuery` with `javascript`. You can't just use `$(this)` inside function to refer `div`. Instead you can use `this` keyword in function passing reference to the `div` and get `innetHTML` from that in `javascript`

```js
function hoverdivOpen(e){
  var v =e.innerHTML;
  console.log(v);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div onmouseover=hoverdivOpen(this)>test</div>
```

Comment: @jotyhista check the updated snippet and updatde answer :)

Comment: Thank you for the help; unfortunately the result is the same :(

Comment: @jotyhista you might be doing something wrong check the snippet it is working fine

Answer (score 0):

First, the reason this is not working is because that object isn't apart of the DOM when the event listener starts.  So there's nothing to listen to.  The way around it, is to attach the event listener to a parent element, and then **delegate to** (cheers, @Sanchit) "focus" in on the dynamic event.  So, say this is your HTML:

```
<div id="my-wrapper"><!-- DYNAMIC ELEMENTS GO HERE --></div>
```

Inside there, you will have dynamic elements (assigning a common class) that you are trying to mouse-over.  So the listener will look like:

```
$("#my-wrapper").on("mouseover", ".common-class", function () {
  $(this).text(); // DO SOMETHING
});
```

Comment: same problem :( I get a blank value with `$(document).on("mouseover", ".info", function () {...}`

Comment: @jotyhista Try wrapping where your dynamic elements will go in a div as opposed to attaching the listener to the document itself, like displayed in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this first div mouseover calls javascript function where as second div uses  jquery

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div onMouseOver="hoverdivOpen('.test')" class="test">test</div>
<div id="popupUserInfoDiv"> 123 </div>
<script>
function hoverdivOpen(divid){
  var v = $(divid).text();
  console.log(v);
  alert(v);
}
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#popupUserInfoDiv').on('mouseover',function(){
alert($(this).text());
});
})
</script>
```